# Microsoft SQL Server backup file very heavy

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have 2.159.000 records now in my table. The table contain:

```
ID -- int
Username -- nvarchar(50)
Password -- nvarchar(50)
Address -- nvarchar(100)
Email -- nvarchar(250)
Note -- nvarchar(250)
Linking - nvarchar(max)
IsBusiness bit
IsActive bit
Delivered - bit
Something1 bit
Something2 bit
Something3 int
Songthing4 int
```

And it's the only one table in my database. But when i run backup using Microsoft SQL server management studio. The output file is up to 6.6 GB. My friend have a database of 9.000.000 records but when he run backup it's only 2.2 GB in same SQL Server 2005. I don't know what could make my database becoming so heavy and i really what to decrease 
it as soon as possible for save my disk.

Comment: Possible your friend backuping database with compression?

Comment: What are you storing in `Linking` column? Each `NVARCHAR(MAX)` field can store up to 2GB of data, so possibly you have something large in there?

Comment: @Devart SQL Server 2005 did not offer backup compression.

Comment: No, but you can use third-party solutions such as LiteSpeed

Comment: @Nenad Zivkovic, I didn't pay attention to this tag.

Comment: @NenadZivkovic Ok, i think the problem is the Linking nvarchar(max) column, even i don't have any data on it. It still spent a lot of space in my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea for you. Duplicate the database so that you have a 2nd copy, drop the linking column out of the table, and then try a backup the new DB. Everything else is fixed-length, so you'll be able to work out if the MAX column contains lots of data.

If it's still huge, then you can look at shrinking the database in case there is some stuck data or space in there. It's generally not required, but can be useful for situations like this.

> DBCC SHRINKDATABASE MyDatabaseName;

Here is more info on how to shrink the DB:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190488(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Ok, i think the problem is the Linking nvarchar(max) column, even i don't have any data on it. It still spent a lot of space in my database.

Comment: In theory this column should only use an amount of data proportional to how much is entered into it. The storage size for each column is (2 x the number of characters) + 2.

Answer (score 1):

The number of rows is almost irrelevant - it's the size of the data within those rows that counts. Your friend might have every row containing half the amount of data in the `Linking` column, for example.

Comment: Ok, i figured out what happen. The problem is the Linking nvarchar(max) column. Even i don't have any data on it. It still spent a lot of space in my database.